# How to make TSynEdit's Wordwrap same as TMemo's?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, synedit

I'm using TSynEdit as a more user-friendly TMemo, mostly for the advanced shortcuts, UNDO/REDO, and so on.

Other things are OK, except the wordwrap behavior, please check the attached screenshot below, SynEdit has a strange space shown on the left-most side.

How to avoid that and make it look like TMemo?

[image]

The TSynEdit's key property settings:

```
    synEdit1.UseCodeFolding := False;
    synEdit1.Options := [eoAutoIndent, eoDragDropEditing, eoEnhanceEndKey, 
eoGroupUndo, eoScrollPastEol, eoSmartTabDelete, 
eoSmartTabs, eoTabsToSpaces];
      synEdit1.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
      synEdit1.TabWidth := 4;
      synEdit1.WantTabs := True;
      synEdit1.WordWrap := True;
      synEdit1.FontSmoothing := fsmNone;
```

Comment: I can't find a way myself either.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Hmm, this behaviour seems to be quite deliberate, but I can't see why it should be.  An odd thing is that depending on the width of the SynMemo, a few lines don't have a starting space.

Comment: Haven't used *SynEdit* for many many years, but I wonder what *eoAutoIndent* does.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  The comment on eoAutoIndent is `Will indent the caret on new lines with the same amount of leading white space as the preceding line`, but neither this nor any of the other `eoXXX` options (including `eoTrimTrailingSpaces`) seem to make any difference to the behaviour in the screen shot: the only thing which *does* is the `WordWrap` property. of the `SynEdit`.  Same is true for the SynMemo, too.

Comment: I guess the intention is that you can see that the text has been wrapped and it's not a newline. Since you have the source code it must be very easy to change the behaviour.

Comment: It is even worse. Sometimes a space is shown, ometimes it is not. I guess it should simply not display the line breaking spaces when wrapping. It doesn't wrpa properly: sometimes it wraps in the middle of a word instead of at the word start.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, correct, that's the intention. I guess it's not easy, since you have to understand the library architecture and read through the source code.

Comment: Well, it's not going to be hard. Look for the Paint method of the control and take it from there.

Comment: It puts the character it wraps on from the source text at the start of the next line instead of at the end of the previous line.  In the example the space between **of** and **the**  is at the end of the first line for TMemo and at the start of the second line for TSynEdit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a complete, tested answer to the q, but may offer the determined
reader a jumping-of point to a functional solution.

The word-wrapping behaviour of a TSynEdit is determined by its current
`TSynWordWrapPlugin`.  The default plugin is defined in SynEditWordWrap.Pas
and contains the procedure `TSynWordWrapPlugin.WrapLines` method, starting at
line 512 in the version I downloaded yesterday using the D10.2.3 GetIt Manager.

Starting at line 560 there is the block of code which, as far as I can tell,
accounts for the space at the start of each wrapped line as illustrated in the q:

```
      if Editor.IsWordBreakChar(vRunner^) then
      begin
        vRowEnd := vRunner;
        break;
      end;
      Dec(vRunner);
```

`vRunner` and `vRowEnd` are among a number of PWideChar variables used in the `WrapLines` method.

Watching the behaviour of this code, which is inside a `while` loop (which is looking for a place to do a word-wrap), it operates
so that when `Editor.IsWordBreakChar(vRunner^)` returns true, the vRunner pointer
has already moved backwards past the word-break char, which is why it (the space) ends
up on the following line, causing the problem noted by the OP.

Changing the code to

```
      if Editor.IsWordBreakChar(vRunner^) then
      begin
        {ma} Inc(vRunner);  //  WARNING: not fully tested
        vRowEnd := vRunner;
        break;
      end;
      Dec(vRunner);
```

forces the vRunner pointer forwards past the word-break character so that the space is included at the end of the line rather than at the start of the next one, so the SynEdit
then displays its wrapped text like the standard TMemo.

Personally, I would not use this change, but would instead see if I could persuade
the SynEdit developers to provide an official solution.  if I *did* use the change
shown above, I certainly wouldn't do it by changing the source of SynEditWordWrap.Pas,
I would do it by writing a replacement for `TSynWordWrapPlugin` and I would include a check that the `inc(vRunner)` does not exceed the valid bounds of the buffer being used to do the word-wrapping.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I definitely will look into it when I use TSynEdit for more than just a memo.

Comment: I confirm @MartynA's suggested changes works at first try! I'll keep monitoring possible issues and update back here.

Comment: not possible wrap & folding at the same time but in advance version could be